# Fetching data from Excel stored in Document Library and displaying it in a list using powershell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I have to fetch data from an Excel document which is stored in my Document Library and display the data in a list. My script runs fine but at `$workbook` it prompts me to pass credentials.

Can this issue be solved?

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity 'http://.....'
$list = $web.Lists['XL List']
$XLSDoc ='http://...'
$SheetName = 'Overall Project Health'
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject 'Excel.Application'
$Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($XLSDoc)....
$Sheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item($SheetName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($XLSDoc, $false, $true)
```

Reference:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195811(office.11).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195811%28office.11%29.aspx)